# In ionic 2 how to iterate ngfor inside an array based on index position?

Tags: angular, ionic2

We have a products array we need some products at the loading of first time then we need to increase one one index position..

html:

```
<div class="item_view" *ngFor="let product of productsArray; let idx = index"></div>
```

with in the div we are displaying our products,we want our products array based on index position.

Comment: I cant understand what is the question, but then again, I'm just a simple man. You want to filter the array or something?

Comment: yes we want to filter the array

Comment: You want to filter it by given index?

Comment: This question is really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this if you want to filter the array by given index

**A pipe**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'indexPipe'
})
export class IndexPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<any>, index?: any): any {
    if (index) {
      return array.filter((item, _index) => {
        return _index == index;
      });
    }

    return array;
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="item_view" *ngFor="let product of productsArray | indexPipe:wantedIndex"></div>
```